# URL redirect from one domain to another using cloudflare

Tags: url, redirect, url-rewriting, cloudflare

I haaave been trying to set up a cloudflare worker to redirecet an URL to another (SOURCE.ie/... -> DESTINATION.com/...).
The destination URL is set up within cloudflare the source-URL however is purchased via Onlydomains.
I have been using the code given in the documentation:

```
const base = "https://DESTINATION.com"
const statusCode = 301

async function handleRequest(request) {
  const url = new URL(request.url)
  const { pathname, search } = url

  const destinationURL = base + pathname + search

  return Response.redirect(destinationURL, statusCode)
}

addEventListener("fetch", async event => {
  event.respondWith(handleRequest(event.request))
})
```

What I think have to do now is to aadd a route but is does not want to do that:
[image]

Although I added the nameservers to the Onlydomains URL.

Am I missing something? I just want a simple redirect that replaces SOURCE with DESTINATION :|

Comment: Are you using Apache server?

Comment: I don't understand why you are trying to do it this way, in order to then develop a more complex application? Otherwise, it's really much easier to just add a rule in the Cloudflare interface ...

Comment: We want to use SOURCE.ie/... as a link shortener for our application. And it needs to be redirected to DESTINATION.com